# How can I debug during installation?

Tags: 8, installation, debugging

I tried to install Drupal 9.4.2 in a MySQL-compatible database, but I got these errors.

> [image: screenshot]

How can I debug during installation or just print out the incompatible SQL statements?

Comment: Line 1213 on that file does not contain a code statement. https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/9.4.2/core/includes/install.core.inc#L1213  Can you confirm the Drupal files are intact? And can you show the site database configuration, minus passwords or other private details? What precisely do you mean by “MySQL-compatible”?

Comment: Are you sure it's not [Drupal 9.3.2](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/9.3.2/core/includes/install.core.inc#L1213)?